# How to add attributes color, font-weight, font-style and text-align inside of c# and using method Replace

Tags: javascript, c#, css

I have this piece of code:

```
enter else
{
    rowData = rowData.Equals("False") || rowData.Equals("True") ? rowData.Replace("False", "No").Replace("True", "Yes") : rowData;
    rowData = rowData.Replace("<img", $"<img width='{contentWidth}' height='100%' ");
    rowData = rowData.Replace("font-size:", "").Replace("font-family:", "");
    rowData = $"<div style= 'font-size:{builder.Font.Size}pt;font-family:{builder.Font.Name};'>{rowData}</div>";
    builder.InsertHtml(rowData);
}
```

But, I need to make changes in attributes color,  font-weight, font-style and  text-align as well. For color, for example, I tried `.Replace("color:","")` and in the next line `color:{builder.Font.Color};`, but I did get it.

Comment: It might help if you show an example of `rowData`, what the current output is, and what your expected output should be.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  your problem is with code you've written, you should include some... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*  A [mcve] should include sample contents for `rowData` as well as your desired final results.  Absent that, your question may be closed as needing debugging details.

Comment: Also, might you please [edit] your question's tags to indicate the languages you are actually using?  You have tagged this as [tag:c#] and [tag:javascript] but `enter else` doesn't seem to be a proper statement in either language.  If you remove the tags for the languages you are not using and add a tag for the language you are using, you're more likely to attract a relevant answer.  See [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).